# Cannot access shared floder on ubuntu from windows 10 meanwhile I have access to default Public folder

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, windows-10, shared-folders

I installed samba and set this configuration below.

[Samba configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHFKP.png)

By default, I have a "Public" folder that is shared with windows and I can access it from windows with out any problem.

[Public Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWCAJ.png)

I shared this hard drive "/media/user_name/Data" via Folder Sharing as you can see below.

[Share Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCg6b.png)

Unfortunately, I was not able to access this folder via windows, meanwhile I can access the "Public" folder as I mentioned earlier.

I tried the change the access permissions of the "Data" folder. I used the following command.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /media/abdelkrim/Data
```

This is the message that I get on windows when I try to access it.

[Windows error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6XVu.png)

I really appreciate your help to solve this issue and make the folder accessible by windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the permissions on Data it's the fact that the system sets up an access control on /media/abdelkrim such that only that user can get to Data.

You have two options:

[1] Move the mount point up a level so that it mounts to `/media/Data` then share that.

[2] Or edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and add a line under `workgroup = WORKGROUP` :

```
force user = abdelkrim
```

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I used the second solution, It worked like a charm.