# Network sharing mounted device. Guest access - permission problem. U.18.04

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, samba

When I am sharing some folder from some of my mounted device, let's say usb pendrive, with the guest access option, the other network linux PC when accessing that folder says:
***Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied***

Sharing folder from the hdd with guest setting is not a problem.

I am quite new to linux so I guess it could be quite a obvious issue and solution, however I could not find a answer quickly "googling"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit **/etc/samba/smb.conf** and add a line under **workgroup = WORKGROUP** :

```
force user = kjahsdf
```

*Replace kjahsdf with your Ubuntu login user name.*

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Reason: [Cannot access shared floder on ubuntu from windows 10 meanwhile I have access to default Public folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169894/cannot-access-shared-floder-on-ubuntu-from-windows-10-meanwhile-i-have-access-to/1169987#1169987)

Comment: Shouldn't that be somehow by default? Should we suggest it to the samba devs? Anyway it worked. Thank you Morbius1